# How to view responsive iframe in both mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css

I have apply below css in iframe for responsive view.Its works fine in Desktop browser but when I view in Mobile Browser ,the iframe display as half screen.Please check below code and advise how to do this...

CSS :-

```
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

/* 4x3 Aspect Ratio */
.iframe-container-4x3 {
  padding-top: 75%;
}
```

HTML:-

```
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/KMYrIi_Mt8A" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about something like below image for mobile
then this is normal behavior as image/video will adjust itself to maintain its aspect ratio

[image]

but if you want to have full height video then refer below code

```
<div>
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/KMYrIi_Mt8A" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
fdfd 

div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ytvmLu3w/

Comment: what ratio to be maintain for mobile ??